# Terraform: How to Inject firewall rules into subnet from a separate module?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, module, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Terraform: What's the best way to apply a set of default firewall rules whenever a subnet is created?

I'm using GCP terraform  modules  & The current design pattern of our terraform is something like below

```
        -> network module -> specific tfvars, local settings per main VPC
       |
        -> subnet module1  -> specific tfvars, local settings for subnet -> specific firewall rules
MY_VPC |
        -> subnet module2  -> specific tfvars, local settings for subnet -> specific firewall rules
       |
        -> subnet module3  -> specific tfvars, local settings for subnet -> specific firewall rules
```

But we have few 10+ organisational policies that states certain "Organisational Firewall rules" needs to be mandated across ALL subnets

What is the best way to INJECT the "Organisational Firewall rules" into all subnets? I was looking for something like in Ansible template, where Terraform can find and replace a "jinja template" with generic

```
# organisational_template
{
 name = "org-standard-1"
 direction = "INGRESS"
 deny = [{ protocol ="tcp", ports="23" }]
}
```

```
# In my subnet module, I can then use as below without actually doing all the 10+ odd
{{organisational_template}}
```

Any idea how to do it in Terraform?
If I create an isolated "organisation standard" module  to insert it POST applying the subnet's, Terraform throws  error as subnet already exists !!

Comment: Did you have considered hierarchical firewall rules? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewall-policies

Comment: yes, i did read that. Actually  I was trying to do exactly that via google-terraform-network https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-network, but it gives me the error saying the network exist ! I understand the reason, why terraform says it exist, as each such module call tries to recreate the entirety (including network)  which is frustrating